# Replacing a fragment in a FrameLayout does not remove the existing fragment from the fragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am adding a fragment dynamically like so:

```
        FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.learn_detail, detailFragment, LEARN_FRAGMENT_THREATS).commit();
        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

I call the same code when I add a different fragment R.id.learn_detail (Which is a Framelayout)

The fragment is replaced fine, but I have noticed that the old fragment still exists in memory.

Calling `mFragmentManager.getFragments` returns a list that gets bigger and bigger with each time I call `replace`. I expected `replace` to destroy the old fragment and add the new fragment in the FrameLayout. Thoughts?

Edit - My problem was that I was always creating a new fragment, no matter what. My complete method ended up looking like this:

```
private LearnPageFragment getPageFragment(LearnPageItem item) {
    LearnPageFragment learnPageFragment = (LearnPageFragment) mFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(LEARN_FRAGMENT_PAGE);

    if (learnPageFragment == null) {
        learnPageFragment = LearnPageFragment.newInstance(item);
    } else {
        //Destroy the view and update the item data
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(learnPageFragment).commit();
        mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        learnPageFragment.getArguments().putSerializable(LearnPageFragment.k_CONTENT, item);
    }
    return learnPageFragment;
}
```

I accepted the answer that put me on the right track. I shouldn't be trying to manually remove fragments from the fragment manager.

Comment: You should remove the existing Fragment first and add new one instead of using replace. :) That's my thought.

Comment: Is that not what replace does? Testing your suggestion now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `FragmentManager` removes a fragment from the UI, the fragment itself is still being managed by the `FragmentManager`.  Aside from finishing its activity, I don't know of a way to specifically tell the `FragmentManager` to "forget" a fragment.

The expectation is that you will reuse fragments you have already created rather than instantiating a new one over and over.  For example, calling `FragmentTransaction.add()` with a tag argument, then calling `FragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()` to get a reference to the fragment.

Comment: I think this is on track to the correct answer. I'm making a new Fragment each time I tap and I'm not checking if the savedInstanceState bundle is null or not. I'm going to work through this some more and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

In Android, `Fragment` back-stack is managed automatically. Doesnt matter if you replace or add a `Fragment`, it'll be added to `Fragment` back-stack.

A way around for what you are asking is you can clear you back-stack each time you want to replace a `Fragment`.

Add following line in your code.

```
FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
```

So your code will look like

```
FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.learn_detail,  detailFragment, LEARN_FRAGMENT_THREATS).commit();
mFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
```

Comment: Interesting. So fragments are added to the back stack even if you call .addToBackStack()?

edit  - I am testing your suggestion now, thanks for the reply